# What do you think of puzzle backgrounds? Maybe old-fashioned?

Tags: website-design, background, critique

please take a look to this fast wireframe:

[image]

It comes from a web designer I work with. We are discussing it, because I perceive the puzzle background as somewhat, don't know, something not modern, quite old fashioned. I don't know where I already saw it, but I'm almost sure I saw it several times, especially in the paset decades, from back in '80ies to '90ties.

So, do you think as me it's and old-fashioned graphic expedient? Do you maybe remember where you already saw somewhere?

Thank you, regards

Comment: Jigsaw puzzles have been around since the mid 1700s.  There probably hasn't been a time since then that they have been unpopular  - so that makes them timeless, or classic, certainly not "old fashioned".

Comment: More than old fashioned is a too inmediate graphic resource

Comment: I have mIxed feelings, yes its cliche and over used but it does convey "work to be done" "problems" "unknown" "puzzles" "searching" "fitting together". The benefit of well used symbols is that their meaning is clear.

Comment: @Webster Interesting. To me, they primarily symbolise fun, game, leisure time, cosiness. That’s the trouble with symbols: their interpretations are so often based on personal experience and history.

Comment: In all of this, as you can see, the page subject is Industry 4.0, so I think that it should all be evaluated also in relation to that.

Answer (score 1):

Make an image search with jigsaw puzzle background. You will get easily hundreds of different versions.

Some of them are "color and edit freely" building blocks for designers, others are made to create some impression depending on

- is it already completed
- is just one piece still missing
- does it cover the whole country with missing pieces
- are there several hands which pour the pieces to their places etc....

Definitely a well used idea, but the generic (uncolored) piece shape probably isn't patented nor copyrighted.